# Mongodb - How can I combine two "query.$or" statements with "query.$and"?

Tags: javascript, filter

I want to filter the documents that satisfy

(title = searchWord OR content = searchWord)
**AND**
(category = category OR category = category).

And I want to combine two OR statements, which are option 1 and 2 below, and I tried to do, but it doesn't work! Please help me to rectify it.

I want to keep the form of option 1 and option 2, and combine the two OR statements with AND .

```
    //option 1
    query.$or = [{ title: searchWord }, { content: searchWord }]; 

    //option 2
    query.$or = [{ category: category }, { category: category }];


    //It doesn't work!!
    query.$and = [{$or : [{ title: searchWord }, { content: searchWord }]},
                  {$or : [{ category: category }, { category: category }]}];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the mongodb query which can be of use to you. It uses an implicit and. Make sure to replace your collectionName.

```
db.collectionName.find({
    $or : [ 
        {"title": searchWord},
        {"content": searchWord}
    ],
    "category": category         
})
```

Comment: I solved the problem. thanks!